# mqtt on rpi zero w

Tags: serial, pi-zero-w, python-3, processor-speed, mqtt

I have rpi zero w system with below spec.

**system specifications:**
micro SD card slot, a mini HDMI port, two micro USB ports (one for power, one for USB), and 512MB of RAM. It has a single-core 700 MHz processor chip, similar to the Pi A+ and B+.

I am using zero in a iot project where less data is transferred hardly 10kb/day. My question is weather a 512mb single core cpu will handle mqtt server. I have already couple of servers running on it. currently my cpu usage goes 100%.

I have a microcontroller plugged in to rpi serial port to read/write, c file which reads/writes serial data consumes more that 60% of cpu.

And a python server running to display the information on web.

I am trying to plug mqtt for push notification to web.(Already tried Push API;service workers ,chrome needs trusted ssl certificates which is out of budget)

Comment: Yes, the Pi Zero will handle a mqtt server.

Comment: How can a c file consume 60% of the CPU, and why is a microcontroller relevant?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev microcontroller is a wireless dongle communicating over zigbee protocol, when ever the dongle has received something, rpi should read it, for that i have a c file running in while loop in non blocking mode. I think while loop is eating away my cpu power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @joan has indicated in her comment, and as suggested in the following which were found by Googling `Pi Zero as MQTT server`, it would seem that the answer to your question is a firm "Yes":

1. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=176689
2. https://www.mickmake.com/post/mqtt-mosquitto-pi-zero-w-5-minutes-tutorial
3. http://www.instructables.com/id/Using-a-Raspberry-PI-Zero-W-As-an-Access-Point-and/

I could go on - and on, and on... and on. It seems this is definitely "do-able". With all of this evidence, I would suggest you try it, and then post here if you have any specific questions. Also, the ["Internet of Things" SE forum](https://iot.stackexchange.com/) may be of interest to you as well.